# Openlayers implement undo feature modify

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using openlayers,

Already I can set feature structure by using modify

and now trying to reset feature structure to the first structure , before modify.

I guess I need to save geometry coordinates before modify
and then setGeometry by the saved   geometry coordinates when click on undo;

Comment: Could you please share the relevant part of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at ol-ext UndoRedo features: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/?q=undoredo
Specially this example show you how to: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.undoredo.html
Be aware the undo/redo is a bit tricky...